# How to create new Mongo ObjectId using variable?

Tags: mongodb, objectid

Can we add a variable inside ObjectId instead of string?

For example:

```js
const _id = ObjectId(variable);
```

or:

```js
let variable = '5defabcty1234ds';


{ '$match': { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(variable) } },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will create the ObjectID from the string, see the documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#specify-a-hexadecimal-string

Edit: The variable will just be replaced to its value (the string) during the execution, so still yes.

Comment: Hey there thanks for the quick reply, one of my mongo query needs to compare the string format of the ObjectId to the database mongo ObjectId, thing is that i get the string from the api call. So could you elaborate on the query how to give the variable name inside mongoose.Types.ObjectId() ,  Thanks in advance